# Secure countdown timer with ajax and django

Tags: ajax, django, security, timer

I'm trying to make a countdown timer similar to the one in rapidshare using ajax and django on the server side.

My ajax call is the following:

```
function loadXMLDoc(url,cfunc){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function getFile(){

    countdown(15);//just shows the counter
    loadXMLDoc("getfiles",function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        document.getElementById("dlzone").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  });
}
```

and on the server side I have a test function:

```
def getfile(request):
    sleep(15)
    return HttpResponse("file")
```

Everything is working as expected except it leaves me wondering if there's a better approach that having the server sleep for 15 seconds. If I did all the waiting using javascript it would be very easy to manipulate variables and bypass the countdown. But still, having the server wait doesn't feel like the best solution. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely the wrong way to do it. You are holding the connection open for 15 seconds, which means that you have to be able to take a ton of connections on your server, even in a moderately loaded scenario.

Instead you should make a call to the server, where you simply set a time when the request will become valid, and then on the client you make the count down. When the countdown is done, you call another function on the server, which checks the timeout (and returns an error if it is too early) before sending the file (or info about the file)

Comment: that definitely sounds like a better approach. So if understand correctly I should have one function to set the due date and another to check if its due. Thanks

Comment: They can be in the same function. If unknown id, then make a new timeout and return how long left. If known id, return the time left if any, otherwise return the download link. You just want to avoid holding the connection...